# What is going on with the FBI's mysterious 'Firefox exploit'?

Tags: exploit, tor

Apparently, the FBI have the ability to 'hack TOR'. There was an operation against a pedophile website this year, to cut a long story short, the feds got the IP addresses of the denizens of the site by a NIT - 'network investigation technique' - it's been strongly inferred that it is a Firefox exploit since the tor browser bundle is basically Firefox.
http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/05/26/judge_torpedoes_tor_pedo/

Anyway, the intresting things are that Mozilla have panicked and are desperate to find out if their browser is leaky, and petitioned the judge (who said no). The judge gave the FBI an ultimatum to disclose the exploit to the defence. The FBI said no - and finally the judge said OK, the evidence is inadmissible. So the FBI chucked a big case which would garner them a heap of arrests and public goodwill. It is being said that the reason is they've found something which is going to pay dividends in the long term. TL;DR I know, but needed to frame the questions properly...

1. Is this 100% likely to be a TOR/ Firefox exploit. (Feds haven't shown themselves to be creative in the past, just found ways of exploiting poor opsec on a grand scale)
2. The website in question is/was on TOR. Would the FBI's 'mystery exploit' work for uncovering the identities of Tor browser user's identities (for example visiting an 'ordinary' webpage (i.e. not in the deep web?) - that the feds were interested in?

Comment: i've heard fbi is sitting on an ff 0day that they used in a targeted attack to install "malware" that then revealed the user's identity. but who knows...

Comment: You're asking us to speculate about an undisclosed vulnerability. Speculation isn't really encouraged on this site

Answer (score 4):

Everything published about this indicates that the FBI seized control of the onion webserver (in doing so, becoming one of the world's largest child porn distributors for a couple weeks, go feds) and then used a [combination of drive-by-malware-downloads](https://www.wired.com/2014/08/operation_torpedo/) and [known plug-in exploits (like Flash)](http://www.tripwire.com/state-of-security/latest-security-news/fbi-used-metasploit-hacking-tool-in-operation-torpedo/) to bypass Tor, rather than actually breaking it.  So, no, the FBI can't "hack Tor", at least not based on this operation.

It's worth nothing that Tor users are advised to disable scripts and plugins precisely because they can be used to bypass Tor and create a direct connection, or query the user's system for identifying information and send it back.  Based on everything that's been made publicly available, this didn't involve zero-day exploits or dazzling technical skills, so much as a child pornography distributor who had a blank administrator password on his website control panel, and users that were using out-of-date plugins and/or insecure browser configurations. Not unlike every run-of-mill malware campaign cyber criminals use ad networks to launch.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this 100% likely to be a TOR/ Firefox exploit.

While nobody except the FBI have the exact details everything known so far suggests that this is an exploit against the browser. It still needs to be delivered to the browser.

> The website in question is/was on TOR. Would the FBI's 'mystery exploit' work for uncovering the identities of Tor browser user's identities (for example visiting an 'ordinary' webpage (i.e. not in the deep web?) - that the feds were interested in?

Since there is nothing specific known about this specific exploit nothing can be said for sure. But if this is an exploit for the browser itself and the attacker has access to a website the victim is using or is controlling a TOR exit node it is not unlikely that he could deliver the exploit to the browser. If the exploit could then be used for permanent system infection (which is a big "if") the attacker might then be able to monitor the users behavior, i.e. also visits to other sites and local files and thus might be able to get the users identity.

But again, these are all speculations and it is unknown if all this can with this specific exploit. But given other vulnerabilities these speculations do not seem to be too far fetched. So even if this specific exploit does not provide this level of access other (still undisclosed or even not yet found) exploits might help.